# Understanding ubuntu command for pgRouting

Tags: ubuntu, openstreetmap

I was just going through the tutorial on this page **[HERE](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/installation.html#data)**.

```
BBOX="-122.8,45.4,-122.5,45.6"
wget --progress=dot:mega -O "sampledata.osm" "http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?*[bbox=${BBOX}][@meta]".
```

I am new to ubuntu and i am struggling to understand the above command. Can somebody help me understand the above command please ?

Answer (score 1):

Taking each command in my question and matching them one by one vis-avis **[THIS](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/wget.htm)** document, answered all my questions , So basically,

the `-o` in the above command is for:

> Log all messages to logfile. The messages are normally reported to
>   standard error.

and the `--progress=type` is for:

> ```
> Select the progress indicator you want to use. Legal indicators are "dot" and "bar".
>
> The "bar" indicator is used by default. It draws an ASCII progress bar graphics (a.k.a "thermometer" display) indicating the status of
> ```
>
> retrieval. If the output is not a TTY, the "dot" bar will be used by
>   default.
>
> ```
> Use --progress=dot to switch to the "dot" display. It traces the retrieval by printing dots on the screen, each dot representing a
> ```
>
> fixed amount of downloaded data.
>
> ```
> When using the dotted retrieval, you may also set the style by specifying the type as dot:style. Different styles assign different
> ```
>
> meaning to one dot. With the "default" style each dot represents 1K,
>   there are ten dots in a cluster and 50 dots in a line. The "binary"
>   style has a more "computer"-like orientation: 8K dots, 16-dots
>   clusters and 48 dots per line (which makes for 384K lines). The "mega"
>   style is suitable for downloading very large files; each dot
>   represents 64K retrieved, there are eight dots in a cluster, and 48
>   dots on each line (so each line contains 3M).
>
> ```
> Note that you can set the default style using the progress command in .wgetrc. That setting may be overridden from the command line. The
> ```
>
> exception is that, when the output is not a TTY, the "dot" progress
>   will be favored over "bar". To force the bar output, use
>   --progress=bar:force.